# Unable to add key for signal-desktop on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: apt, keyrings

I am trying to install the Singal desktop application on my Ubuntu 20.10 using the commands [here](https://signal.org/download). They are as given below:

```bsh
# 1. Install our official public software signing key
wget -O- https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | sudo apt-key add -

# 2. Add our repository to your list of repositories
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list

# 3. Update your package database and install signal
sudo apt update && sudo apt install signal-desktop
```

It get stuck at step #1 only. I tried downloading key manualling and then adding it using `sudo apt-key add 'keys.asc` but it gave me the same error.

Error:

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
gpg: invalid key resource URL '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.AVkbXq0uHG/home:manuelschneid3r.asc.gpg'
gpg: keyblock resource '(null)': General error
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 40976EAF437D05B5: 60 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 76F1A20FF987672F: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 1488EB46E192A257: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 1488EB46E192A257: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: Total number processed: 20
gpg:       skipped new keys: 20
```

Comment: Those repos are for Xenial, which is 16.04. You’ll likely need to find Signal repos for Focal instead.

Comment: @Matigo I believe keys are the same for all in step 1. It is step 2 where the distribution is mentioned as xenial.

Answer (score 0):

I went down a very long rabbit hole on this same issue, and found that I needed to eliminate a bad key file:

sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:manuelschneid3r.asc

.. then run the steps again; worked like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `home:selmf.asc` and `home:selmf.gpg` from `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` fixed it for me.

Either move the files to your home directory so in case something breaks you can revert it:

```
mv "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:selmf.asc" "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:selmf.gpg" ~/
```

or delete them completely:

```
rm "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:selmf.asc" "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:selmf.gpg"
```